# Not enough values to unpack ValueError, how to fixe it for sys.stdin.read() in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started programming in Python, and I'm currently using Spyder. Whenever I try to run this code, I get :

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

I have checked it, but I don't understand why I have an error. I know I can use input() instead. However, i would like to know what's happening.
Thanks

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def gcd_naive(a, b):
    current_gcd = 1
    for d in range(2, min(a, b) + 1):
        if a % d == 0 and b % d == 0:
            if d > current_gcd:
                current_gcd = d

    return current_gcd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    a, b = map(int, input.split())
    print(gcd_naive(a, b))
```

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdin.read()` instead of `input()` in the first place? BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: I was trying to run the example code from a course. Thank you so much!

Comment: `input` is the name of a built-in function. Do not use it for your variables.

Comment: If i change it to any other i get the same result.

Comment: If you use `input()` and type two numbers separated by a single space it will work.